# Is there any way to export Point Cloud data from LiDAR iOS14?

Tags: ios, arkit, metalkit, realitykit, lidar

I am new for Metal and ARkit. I started learning about Lidar and scene’s depth data to visualize the shape. Below is the link for the point cloud sample code provided by Apple Developers.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/visualizing_a_point_cloud_using_scene_depth

Can someone please help me how to export the 3D file for the point cloud or some guidance that how to achieve Or is there any way to convert the point cloud data to MDLMesh so that i can export file from it.